# How AwesomiumSharp handles asynchronous calls from Javascript to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, awesomium

I'm working on AwesomiumSharp version1.6.6 now. And use CreateObject & SetObjectCallback to build bridge between Javascript and C#, then Javascript can call methods of C#.

And as known, calls from Javascrip to C# is asynchronous. But when I fired two calls to C# in a row. Just the first call is handled by C# normally, the other seemed to be disregarded. I want to know how Awesomium handles async calls.

I just want to guarantee all asynchronous calls from Javascript can be handled normally, how can I achieve this?

Comment: if you want fine-grained control over your ajax calls, try making them yourself instead of using `SetObjectCallback`.

Comment: Do you mean that it's not feasible to achieve what I want via AwesomiumSharp's API?

Comment: I am not familiar with the API so I can not say for sure. What I am sure of is that you'd have all the control you want if you made the ajax calls manually.

Comment: I'm still confused that conversely, if I send a call request to Javascript from C#, there would be a thread in Awesomium triggering a event and adding related callback to the job queue of Javascript V8 engine. Is that right? And if so, why asynchronous calls from Javascript to C# wouldn't be handled rightly.. That'll make things very handy.